# Calculating difference of the values in same column of table by a date column of other table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some tables as shown in the image in Power BI. Basically I need to calculate the difference for a column named ACT Renew (Data type: whole number) listed in table RET ALL depending upon the Fiscal Year column from SQLServerDateTable.

So potentially the created measure should list the value as:
Value = ( sum of ACT Renew where fiscal year = 2018) - (sum of ACT Renew where fiscal year =2017 )

I already have setup the relationship between these tables and from filtering perspective everything in syncing fine, I know this is much easy from filtering and I am able to do that but according to the requirement I need to write a measure for this to show it as a tile.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to filter inside of `CALCULATE` to do this and if the tables are related it should just work.

```
MeasureValue = 
    CALCULATE(SUM('RET all'[ACT Renew]), SQLServerDateTable[FiscalYear] = 2018) -
    CALCULATE(SUM('RET all'[ACT Renew]), SQLServerDateTable[FiscalYear] = 2017)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. I had tried the same Dax earlier but i was putting "2018" instead of 2018 and it was giving me comparison error. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: Quick question: What if I have to use the WeekEndingDate (its a date column )instead of the Fiscal Year. For example if i need to filter between date period in the above DAX, how would that work. Sorry a bit new to the DAX queries.